# How to make tqdm play nice with jenkins?

Tags: jenkins, tqdm

Love [tqdm](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/tqdm) progress bar, but when I use it on jenkins, I keep getting a bunch of weird artifacts and too much bloat in stdout (specifically, omnipresence of `[A`). Is there a secret mode in tqdm to make it work nicely with jenkins? Bonus points for seamless detection of non-interactive shells like jenkins. Here is what my typical output looks like:

```
label: 0it [00:00, ?it/s][A
[A
 16%|#6        | 5378/33302 [36:28<2:30:49,  3.09it/s]
[A
 16%|#6        | 5379/33302 [36:29<2:36:46,  2.97it/s]
[A
...
```

Comment: There is an `ascii` option in tqdm constructor.

Comment: This is an open [Jenkins Issue](https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49918)

Answer (score 4):

I'd go with something like:

```py
from tqdm import tqdm
import os

# try this
for i in tqdm(..., disable=None):
    ...

# alternative if the above doesn't work
for i in tqdm(..., disable=os.environ.get("JENKINS_HOME")):
    ...

# or even...
for i in tqdm(..., disable=os.environ.get("JENKINS_HOME") is not None):
    ...
```

Note that `disable=None` should automatically check things such as `sys.stdout.isatty()`.

Unfortunately there's nothing that can be done about Jenkins not supporting `CR` (`\r`), a basic requirement of `tqdm`.

From https://tqdm.github.io/:

> `tqdm` does not require any dependencies (not even `curses`!), just Python and an environment supporting carriage return `\r` and line feed `\n` control characters.